# Two Grails relationship between two tables - transient object exception

Tags: grails, grails-orm, hibernate-mapping, relationships

I'm working on a genealogy project.  The problem is with two tables - the Person and Marriage tables.

The marriage class looks like this:

```
class Marriage implements Serializable{
 Person husband
 Person wife
 String notes 
}
```

The primary key is the `husband.id` and the `wife.id`.

The person class looks like this:

```
Class Person{
 //lots of members
 Marriage parents
}
```

Everything works, except adding parents to a person that's already created, but without parents, i.e. updating the person.  There's no problem getting the right marriage to add to this person.  Creating a person from scratch and adding a marriage to him works.  I use much the same code.  It works for `save()` but not for `update()`

Here's the problem:  `org.hibernate.TransientObjectException - object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing`:  - it's the Marriage object.  It exists in the database and is clearly visible.  Using the Grails console I have no problem accessing it.

I've tried `belongsTo` and `hasOne`, no go.

Any idea what to do?  I'd like to keep the composite key, it causes me no problems and prevents the same two people entering in another marriage - the notes can deal with that if they do.

Answer (score 0):

what you see in the DB CAN NOT cause the `TransientObjectException`.
It looks like you are trying to save an `perso` instance, the `marriage` instance cannot be saved.
Print out the `errors` properties for both objects to see if they can be saved

Comment: It gets worse - both the person and the marriage (between two other persons) are saved and visible in the database.  I've tried it with the new Hibernate 4 and the old Hibernate 3, the same result.

Comment: It gets worse - both the person and the marriage (between two other persons) are saved and visible in the database.  I've tried it with the new Hibernate 4 and the old Hibernate 3, the same result.  Creating a new person and adding the married couple as his parents at the time of his creating causes no problems.  It's only when a person previously created without parents is updated with a previously created married couple as his parents that this happens.It happens when I try retrieving that married couple from the database, even before adding the couple as his parents and saving the new him.

Comment: share some code, how you get the objects, assign them to each other and save/update

Comment: Got it, but it's not an elegant solution.  I simply do Marriage.list() and iterate through it till the right one pops up and return it.  Here's the Pair class:<code>

Comment: Got it, but it's not an elegant solution.  I simply do Marriage.list() and iterate through it till the right one pops up and return it.  Here's the Pair class: 
class Pair implements Serializable {
 Person husband
 Person wife
 String notes                                                                    
 static mapping = {
  id composite: ['husband', 'wife']
 } 
}
 The Person class: class Person {
 String name
    String surname
    String gender
    Pair parents
}
No belongsTo or hasMany.  That causes problems. It shows pairs as their own children.

Comment: No, what it was, was taking the transactional annotation away.